# Vimで一番内側のbracesやbracketsの外側にカーソルを移動させる

Tags: vim

Vimで一番内側のbracesやbracketsの外側に飛ぶ方法は何かありますか?
(例1)のような位置にカーソルがあるときに、(例2)のようにifの外側に持って行きたいのです。
`}`(段落ごとに下へ)を使ってはみたのですが、それだと一番外側(functionの外側)まで移動してしまいます。
なにか方法はあるのでしょうか?

(例1)

```
function () {
    if (...) {
        |
    }
}
```

(例2)

```
function () {
    if (...) {

    }|
}
```

Comment: ノーマルモード中ということでよろしいですか？
あと、(例2)のカーソル位置が `}` の後ろにありますが、これは `}` の後ろにスペースかタブがあるということでしょうか？もしくは `set virtualedit=all`等を設定しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ノーマルモードで今いるブロックの最後`}`に移動するには `]}` と入力します。(`:h ]}`)
(ブロックの最初`{`に移動するには `[{` です)

`}`の後ろにスペースかタブがあって移動可能な場合は `]}` の後にスペースもしくは`l`を押して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

}の外側に空白でもあればいいのですが（文字のないところに移動はできないようですから）なければ、行末に追加'A'なのですが移動方法がいまいちよくわからない。一番内側なら/}で検索してaかなぁ？　私なら上の{に移動して%aとやりますが・・行番号がわかればxxGAで移動できるけど
いずれの場合も挿入モードになりますｄ＾＾；